# Simple sip based client interaction... Any Ideas

Tags: voip, sip

I am tring to do the following:

I want a SIP User Agent to perform the following steps on receiving an inbound call (call set up request).

1) Read the caller ID from the SIP request and Log the details to file

2) Drop the call (terminate the call without picking up the call)

I have not been able to find a high level api that will let me script this interaction. I have taken a look at Jain but it seems to be a very low level API and I imagine will require a lot of work to get the above interaction coded up and working. Can anyone suggest an apropriate API to implement the above.

NOTE: I have tried ROXEO.com and their CCXML based apps are great but their pricing is aimed at big companies, so Voxeo is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few open source SIP stacks around two examples of many are [pjsip](http://www.pjsip.org/) and [sipsorcery](http://www.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?ProjectName=sipsorcery) (as a disclaimer I do some dev work on the latter). It will all depend on your language and prefeences as to which one suits. There are also lots of SIP tools around that may be a more efficient approach for you such as [SIPp](http://sipp.sourceforge.net/).

Apart from those options and given your very simple requirements you could probably get away with 20 or 30 lines of code that listens on a UDP socket, parses the incoming INVITE to extract the From header and then sends back a rejection response by changing the top line of the request to make it a response and sending it back to where it came from.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C, try eXosip, you could easily whatever you want.
[Here](http://www.antisip.com/documentation/exosip2/group__howto1__initialize.html)

It's clear that Jain SIP could be quite painful (actually all the configuration but the API otherwise is quite high-level, to manipulate messages) , but you can take the jain-sip-presence-proxy and removes almost everything from their INVITE handler and build your own message

Answer (score 0):

if you're using java, you can use [peers](http://peers.sourceforge.net/) which provides a high level api in package net.sourceforge.peers.sip.core.useragent. The entry point is UserAgent class, take a look at gui package if you want to see how it is used. Traces are in log files so you can track calls.

Answer (score 0):

ivrworx but it can handle one scenarion at a time only

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk pbx can act as a simple sip client, and do just that, however if you wante to integrate something in your own solution, take a look at: http://sipsimpleclient.org/projects/sipsimpleclient/wiki/SipMiddlewareApi